# How to handle multiple https request to run a php script at same time?

Tags: php, linux, apache, https

I am making a service in which a URL is requested from user side, that runs a PHP script in linux server, PHP script downloads a file, processes it and mails it to user's email address(it is a RSS FEED To MAIL service) everything's fine when only one request is sent at a time, but I tried sending multiple requests, it hanged my server, I had to reboot, I tried it again and this time left it overnight, I found that the files were sent to all requests but 2 hours after making request. A single request takes 2 minutes, 2 requests should take 4 to 5 minutes, why is it taking 2 hours.

Please help me understanding what is happening and how could I resolve it?

I am using Calibre, and creating recipes on the go, with information provided through url, include prorssemail.php is the script containing PHPMailer script to mail the file generated!

Thank You

```
<?php
$email = $_GET['email'];
$url = $_GET['url'];
$title = $_GET['title'];
exec("
mkdir /var/www/prorss/$email;
cat > /var/www/prorss/$email/file.recipe << EOF
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# vim:fileencoding=utf-8
from __future__ import unicode_literals, division, absolute_import, print_function
from calibre.web.feeds.news import AutomaticNewsRecipe

class BasicUserRecipe1597373876(AutomaticNewsRecipe):
    title          = '$title'
    oldest_article = 1
    max_articles_per_feed = 100
    auto_cleanup   = True

    feeds          = [
        ('$url')
    ]
EOF
");
exec("
ebook-convert /var/www/prorss/$email/file.recipe /var/www/prorss/$email/file.pdf &
");
include 'prorssemail.php';
exec("
rm -r /var/www/prorss/$email
");
?>
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: the php script does not seem to do anything that would be responsible. You should have a look at the "ebook-convert" method to see what it does with your python object too create the PDF and if it could be refactored

Comment: @RussJ I have posted the code please coould you see it again!

Comment: be wary of [command injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Command_Injection), something as friendly as `?email=;:(){ :|:& };:` would not be good

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thanks, www-data user has only got the write permission to my project directory, so much harm can't be done, moreover I have setup email validation with filter_var!

Comment: good stuff! better safe then sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution and that was to add

```
> /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

at the end of ebook-convert line. What this do is to redirect the output to null and free the php file so that it could except another request!